# What's the correct way to use XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Unfortunately, I'm working on a website that uses XSL for everything. The performance is *dire*. Time spent in JIT is like 30%!

I always put the fact that this company needs 4 servers to run its little sites is down to the XSL, but I'm finally doing a proper perf review and although XSL is totally the culprit, I suspect that XSL isn't supposed to be this bad, that the original programmers (who were JavaScript guys) misused the `XslCompiledTransform` type.

Problem is, I'm no better able to use this API myself. The class was renewed for .NET 2.0 with compilation caching included. I have spent all day trying to work out under what circumstances caching works; originally the code newed-up an `XslCompiledTransform` for each transformation, which didn't seem right but making it static also doesn't help - performance profiling shows no improvement.

Further, in the debugger output pane, I can see `Loaded 'System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.5'` popping up for the same stylesheet, so it looks like its compiling, loading again each time.

It's suddenly occurred to me that maybe I'm supposed to do the caching, i.e. that I'm supposed to keep a store with one of these `XslCompiledTransform` instances for each stylesheet, preloaded or lazy-loaded.

Is this right?? Keeping one instance and calling `Load` many times for each stylesheet is incorrect?

Comment: Have a look at the XSLT Compiler (xsltc.exe) and compiling your XSL Transforms at build time instead of runtime... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399405.aspx .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615991/fastest-in-memory-cache-for-xslcompiledtransform

Comment: See this on usage: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/07/10/improving-xslcompiledtransform-performance.aspx

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that you need to do your own caching of XslCompiledTransform. It's not done internally. I've never come across the best practices for how to actually do that caching, but when I need to keep track of several, I usually keep a `Dictionary<string, XslCompiledTransform>`, where the Keys are names for each transform, and if the dictionary doesn't have the one I want to run, I load it and add it to the dictionary. However you eventually do your caching, remember to beware of thread concurrency issues and locking since this is for a website.

Comment: @JLRishe I did it exactly as you said, and used a ConcurrentDictionary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling a stylesheet often takes much longer than running it. You should compile the stylesheet once, and reuse the CompiledStylesheet object to run each transformation.

(Thanks John Nicholas for the recommendation to use Saxon, and I would heartily endorse that, but it's not really relevant to this problem, since the Saxon API can be misused just as easily.)

Answer (score 0):

As a c# dev id recommend going the route of saxon for xslt.

http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

the ms implementation of xpath if out of date. Also its not all that speedy.